# Why the CLIPS Eval function did not work same in CLIPSCRLWrapper.dll as it in IDE

Tags: c#, clips

I am developing a WPF application in C# which uses the CLIPS expert system engine in some of its parts.I used the CLIPSCRLWrapper.dll which Gary developed.
Here is my C# code :

```
clips.Load("ATC.clp");
clips.Eval("(Clear)");
clips.Reset();
clips.Run();
sring evalStr="(find-all-facts ((?f ATCOutPut)) TRUE)";
FactAddressValue fv =(FactAddressValue)((MultifieldValue)clips.Eval(evalStr))[0];
```

But,the project crushed in the last line code.and after debuging ,i find the the program runs into this code snippet:

```
if(rc==0)
{
std::string excStr="Eval: Invalid expression";
excStr.appennd(evalString);
throw std::logic_error(excStr);
}
```

However,when i load the "ATC.clp" in the IDE,type in “(find-all-facts ((?f ATCOutPut)) TRUE)”,then it returns

> Fact-1

And i also read the "clips_dotnet_010" code that Gary posted,the C# code above is almost the same with Gary's.But mine just crushed.I don't know why.

So,the same eval string get diffrent results int DLL and the IDE.
Please help me ,how can i get the same result in CLIPSCRLWrapper.dll as the IDE ?

And, the code in "ATC.clp" like below:

```
(deftemplate ATCOutPut
(slot name (type SYMBOL)(default nil))
(slot end (type STRING)(default ""))
(slot planetype(type STRING)(default ""))
(slot landingtype(type STRING)(default ""))
(slot value (type NUMBER)(default 5000))
(slot ID(type INTEGER)(default 0))
)

(deffacts InitATC
(ATCOutPut (name NONE))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your code:

```
clips.Eval("(Clear)");
```

There is no command in clips named Clear with a capital C. If your intent is to call the clear command in CLIPS through the Eval method, it doesn't make sense to do this after you've loaded constructs and you can do this using a "clips.Clear();" method call instead of calling the Eval method.

Comment: but,it does not work.it just crushed in the last line:"FactAddressValue fv =(FactAddressValue)((MultifieldValue)clips.Eval(evalStr))[0];",I have worked on this for several days,and still can not make it .So,you are my only hope.

Comment: The most likely explanation is that your rules didn't load because the working directory of your program is not the same directory where the rules file is located.

Comment: I found the problem finally,that is I using Windows 10.when i copy the project to Win7,it compiled successfully.Thanks a lot for your attention.

Comment: Update：after some tests,i found that the Windows 10 whose version before 1607 can not debug the DLL ,and those after 1607 can debug successfully.